# How to force my custom styles?

Tags: html, css, custom-controls

I have a widget with some custom styles for buttons, edit boxes and etc. But this widget is working on a page, which also has custom styles for these elements. So, the host page styles and my widget styles interfere.

Is it possible to protect my widget from foreign styles somehow?

I want only my styles work on my widget.

**P.S.**

Probably, I can enclose my entire widget with `<div id="widgetname">` and prepend all my styling with `#widgetname * { ...some clearing rules ...}` and then have all my styles with `#widgetname` prefix? Something in that manner?

Comment: make sure your custom styles have a higher [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), or (as a last resort) add !important to your custom styles.

Comment: The enclosing would work, but you can not avoid the user loads CSS overriding your settings on their pages.

Comment: @ptriek, thanks, have increased specificity and got what I wanted; but I still wonder, if it is possible to avoid extra rules applying at all?

Answer (score 0):

put #widgetname and its corresponding classes at the bottom of your stylesheet
if your widget still inherit from other, use !important